# org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition; class invalid for deserialization

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am writing a spark streaming app using spark 1.6.2 and kafka 0.10.0.1, I run the app on yarn, it runs fine most of time, but in some cases, I met the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition; class invalid for deserialization
```

I really cannot figure it out why this happen. Has anybody met this issue before? How to solve it please? Any help is appreciated!

My code is like this: I got offset for my topic from zookeeper,

```
val fromOffsets: Map[TopicPartition, Long] = getMyOffsetMethod()
```

Then I use this to create a dstream,

```
consumerStrategy = ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String]
(Set(topic), kafkaConf, fromOffsets)
linesDStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
  ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers, consumerStrategy)
```

Is this reason which caused this issue? Also @Matthias J. Sax, it is deserialization, not serialization

Comment: can you add codes how you use TopicPartition?

Comment: It seems, that some part of the code tries to serialize a variable of type `TopicPartition`. You might need to annotate this member with `@transient`

Comment: Pls see my edit

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue with yarn. However, by switching to master local the error is gone....does anyone has find any solution to it?